# postgresql - losing command prompt after select from quoted table name

Tags: postgresql

At a relational database command prompt, normally if you enter a query, then you get data back, followed by a new command prompt.  Postgresql does this for me too when I select from a table with no quotes in the name.  I'm trying to debug the Postgresql setup for [a sample Scala application that uses quoted table names](https://github.com/manuelbernhardt/reactive-web-applications/tree/master/CH07), though, and when I select from one of these manually with psql, I get the data, but it is followed by text on an inverted-color background that says

```
(END)
```

instead of a new command prompt, and I can't seem to get the command prompt back.  What's going on?  I haven't found mention of this behavior of Postgresql anywhere.

I'm using a new install of Postgresql 9.3 on Ubuntu 14.04. Attempting to follow instructions in the book the above-linked sample application came from, I'm executing

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
email varchar NOT NULL,
password varchar NOT NULL,
firstname varchar NOT NULL,
lastname varchar NOT NULL
);
```

Then I'm executing something in the sample application that through a lot of indirection ends up inserting a single row to this table.  I don't think the details of this should be relevant.  Then as a test I am manually executing the following in psql:

```
select * from "user";
```

This ought to be about as trivial as you can get.  I'm an old hand at Oracle, but completely new to Postgresql. I see that using quoted names is considered bad practice by many, but I'm trying not to perturb the sample application any more than I have to.

How do I get my command prompt back?

Comment: It's not related to quoted names. Look for **pager** in the psql manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html for how to configure it if you don't like the default behavior.

Comment: I think it only gives that (END) line if you are selecting *  or the result is longer than your terminal.  When I do SELECT * FROM users I get the (END) but like @andreas-hofmann said q worked for me to enter another query, but when I try SELECT first_name FROM users I do not get the (END) and my terminal is ready for another query.

Answer (score 3):

After a query is returned and the results are being displayed, psql switches to a vi/less-like view of the results. Try hitting *q* to exit that view again and your command prompt should return.

Answer (score 0):

We can return back to original terminal by giving Ctrl+C. This works for me in Psql Version 12.